# How to avoid mutations of objects while pushing them in an array?

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, oop

I'm coding a library that allow you to save books by filling a form, simple as that.

When you click the submit button of the form and triggers `addBook()`, `newBook` stores the values of the form in an instance of `Book` class which only holds the data.

After that, if the book is not in the library then adds it to the class `Library` which have a function `addBook()` that receives and pushes every `newBook` in an array (`this.books`) that is inside the constructor of the class.

Then `updateBooksGrid()` iterates over `library.books` (the array) with a for loop and creates new books in the UI.

At first it works when you generate the first book, but for some weird reason, when you do it a second time you only modify the first element. I verified that `library.books` works correctly since it creates another object, but the only one being modified directly is `newBook`. I don't understand why or how this is happening if I made sure to reset the form every time you open it with `reset()` method.

```
// Data Structures

class Book {
    constructor(
        title = 'Unknown',
        author = 'Unknown',
        pages = '0',
        isRead = false
    ) {
        this.title = title;
        this.author = author;
        this.pages = pages;
        this.isRead = isRead;
    }
}

class Library {
    constructor() {
        this.books = [];
    }

    addBook(newBook) {
        this.books.push(newBook)
    }

    isInLibrary(newBook) {
        return this.books.some((book) => book.title === newBook.title);
    }
}

let library = new Library();

// utils 
const $ = id => document.getElementById(id);



// User interface

const $gridContainer = $('container');
const $addBookBtn = $('addBtn');
const $submitBtn = $('submit');
const $overlay = $('overlay');
const $bookForm = $('bookForm');
const $errorMsg = $('errorMsg');

function openAddBookModal() {
    $bookForm.reset();
    addBookModal.classList.add('active');
    $overlay.classList.add('active');
}

function closeAddBookModal() {
    addBookModal.classList.remove('active');
    $overlay.classList.remove('active');
    $errorMsg.classList.remove('active');
}

const updateBooksGrid = () => {
    for(let book of library.books) {
        createBookCard(book);
    }
}

function createBookCard(book) {
    $gridContainer.innerHTML = `
    <div class='book-card'>
      <h1>"${book.title}"</h1>
      <p>${book.author}</p>
      <p>${book.pages}</p>
      <div class='btn-container'>
      </div>
    </div>
    `
}

const getBookFromInput = () => {
    const title = $('title').value;
    const author = $('author').value;
    const pages = $('pages').value;
    const isRead = $('isRead').checked;
    return new Book(title, author, pages, isRead);
}

const addBook = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const newBook = getBookFromInput();

    if(library.isInLibrary(newBook)) {
        $errorMsg.innerText = 'This book already exists in your library';
        $errorMsg.classList.add('active');
        console.log(library.books);
        return;
    } else {
        library.addBook(newBook);
        updateBooksGrid();
    }

    console.log("from the function", newBook);
    console.log("from the class", library.books);
    closeAddBookModal();
}


$addBookBtn.onclick = openAddBookModal;
$overlay.onclick = closeAddBookModal;
$bookForm.onsubmit = addBook;
```

the HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Library App</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./styles.css" />
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@500;600;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.png" />
    <script
      src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c536a6bd5.js"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar">
            <h1>my library</h1>
            <span class="btn login-btn">log in</span>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <div class="books-grid" id="container"></div>
        <button class="btn add-btn" id="addBtn">add new book +</button>
    </main>
    <footer class="footer">
      <p>
        Copyright ©
        <script>
          document.write(new Date().getFullYear())
        </script>
        AsherCode
      </p>
      <a href="https://github.com/Alpha18-coder" target="_blank">
        <i class="fab fa-github"></i
      ></a>
    </footer>

    <div class="modal" id="addBookModal">
        <form class="book-form" id="bookForm">
            <label for="title">
                book's title:
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="title"
                    required
                    maxlength="100"
                >
            </label>

            <p class="error-msg" id="errorMsg"></p>
            <label for="author">
                author:
                <input 
                    type="text" 
                    id="author"
                    required
                    maxlength="100"
                >
            </label>
           
            <label for="pages">
                number of pages:
                <input 
                    type="number" 
                    id="pages"
                    required
                    max="10000"
                >
            </label>
           
            <div class="read-status">
                <label for="isRead">
                    have you read it?
                    <input class="checkbox" type="checkbox" id="isRead" />
                </label>
                
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn submit-btn" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="overlay" id="overlay"></div>
</body>
<script defer src="./main.js"></script>
</html>
```

Comment: We are missing some important code I guess

Comment: there's no Array in the code - so I would assume you're *doing something wrong™* in code you haven't shown ... or perhaps you don't understand what the code you haven't shown is doing - either way, you've shown the wrong code

Comment: @JaromandaX i edited the post so hopefully you will understand it now, but yeah i believe there's a part of my code i still don't understand yet. i took this code from this repository  https://github.com/michalosman/library

Comment: I don't see an error in this code, although you are missing the `Book` class. You also check *twice* if the book already exists or not. Please add the complete code, including HTML, so we can reproduce the error.

Comment: @Kokodoko this time i added the HTML and refactored the code, I just implemented the dollar sign and followed the Jquery style so it can be more readable this time.

Comment: I have put your code in a JSFiddle, see here: https://jsfiddle.net/cejhrb7n/  I still don't see any error. You can create a new book from the form fields, and when you click `submit` it will be added to the array. The old book is not overwritten. So I think your error must be somewhere else.

Comment: The weird thing about this is that the UI doesn't work correctly because it's directly modified there. Can i contact you on discord? because i believe this needs a more personalized attention

Comment: I found the problem! it's the `innerHTML`